# Asp.net MVC and Subsonic 3 installation

Tags: subsonic3

I am new to Subsonic3. Want to create a project using MVC and subsonic 3.
I am not sure how to install subsonic3 in my web application?
Is there any installer available for subsonic so that i can find "Asp.net MVC Subsonic 3" project type while creating new project?
Any best pattern to create subsonic3 with Asp.net MVC?

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.set a db connection in your web.config
2. set the name of the connection in your setting.tt
3. set the namespace to yournamespace.Models
4. drag all tt files into the models folder on VS

thats it, TT files are the installation files, when a TT file is added
it triggers a build action within VS and creates all the classes for you
this is why subsonic is so fantastic, you dont have to think about how it will be done
and what needs to be done, you just ell it where the DB lives and thats it.

rob did a musical video here to show how quick it is, and it is really that quick

[Subsonic demo](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/The_5_Minute_Demo)